# What is "point of interest" and why isn't there a Zref for determining electron beam quality with TRS 398?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering, medical-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

What is "point of interest" and why isn't there a Zref for determining electron beam quality with TRS 398?
[image]

((To what depth do you put the ion chamber when you do high energetic electron beam quality with TRS 398?))

Comment: Maybe you should consider putting a lot more background into this question like, where this table comes from and what your variables mean that you are looking for help with.